# CakePHP - input select not taking select options from a variable

Tags: forms, cakephp, select, input, cakephp-2.3

I am developing an application with CakePHP 2.3.2 and I am having some trouble with an input select on a form. I am creating an array, in my Controller, which contains a list of states. In my View I find that when I use this variable in the 'options' field of the input I do not get any select options. If I do a print_r on the variable, in the view, I see exactly what I think I should be seeing for the 'options' field. I have even tried copying this print_r output and putting it in the 'options' field and then the input select works fine.

Here is what I have

In Controller

```
$options = 'array(1 => \'NSW\',2 => \'ACT\',3 => \'NT\');
$this->set('all_states, $options);
```

In View

```
<?php
$options = $all_states;

echo $this->Form->create('Refine', array('url => '/ServiceDirectoryResults/view/refine'));

echo $this->Form->input('field' ,array(
   'type' => 'select',
   'label' => false,
   'options' => $options
));

echo $this->Form->end('Refine Search');

?>
```

When I run this I see a select with no select options

If I add print_r($options) after the echo $this->Form->end('Refine Search'); I see

```
array(1 => 'NSW',2 => 'ACT,3 => 'NT')
```

Which is what I would expect as it is the content of the $options variable which was the $all_states variable passed from the controller. If I take this output from the print_r and replace the $option with it in the input select the select drop down works fine and I see the three options. For some reason I can't work out the select is working fine if I hard code the select options but it will not work if I pass a variable containing the array to the input select.

I would really appreciate if if someone could give me a clue what I am doing wrong here.

Kind Regards

Richard

Comment: Please make sure the provided code mirrors your code exactly... as you can see even by the StackOverflow color-coding, there are missing quotation marks all over, and don't know if that's the problem with your code, or just a typo in your question.

Answer (score 2):

you might try it like below:

```
echo $this->Form->input('field', array('type'=>'select','label' => false,
   'options' => $options,'default'=>'2'));
```

to the following HTML being generated:

```
<option value="2" selected="selected">ACT</option>
```

option two is shown instead any other one.

Answer (score 0):

**Likely issue:**

Arrays should not be made as strings like you have:

```
$options = 'array(1 => \'NSW\',2 => \'ACT\',3 => \'NT\');
```

Instead, just make an array:

```
$options = array(1 => 'NSW', 2 => 'ACT', 3 => 'NT');
```

**Other notes:**

- Why are you setting `$options` to `$all_states` only to set it back?
- Missing quotes all over - make sure if you start quotes, that you also end them
- not good practice to hard-code your URLs (like in your Form->create)

Comment: Thanks @Dave 

That was the problem with the options array.

On your other notes

The setting $options and setting it back was a left over from some earlier code. Of course it should not be done. Thanks for picking it up

Missing quotes? Where was I missing quotes "all over"?

I realise it is not a good practice to hard code the URL but it was the only way I could get the form to post to where I wanted it to go.

Thanks for your help

Richard

Comment: Not "was" - you still "are" missing quotes all over - after "ACT" and "url" as examples.  Maybe those were the only 2 - not sure, but it's enough to cause your color coding to be unreadable.